# Can the SQL query for an Azure Function's Cosmos DB input binding be called dynamically, with variables, from within the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection of temperature values with timestamps in Azure Cosmos DB from which I want to query the average temperature value from a particular upload date.

I currently have a working solution using the [@azure/cosmos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos) client library, which allows me to dynamically build and execute queries against my temperature collection from an Azure Function.

I was wondering if it was possible to execute dynamic SQL queries against a Cosmos DB input binding, rather than using the cosmos client library, simply for performance benefits?

Also, if this is possible, would using the input binding actually afford a performance benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it depends on what you meant with dynamic. If you meant the query changes based on input from your request(**HttpTrigger**) then the answer is yes it can.
Example:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.temperature > {temp} AND (c.expired?? false) = false`

Here `{temp}` is replaced with data in your request body eg.

```
{
  "deviceId": "22dsa2d55f",
  "temp": 55.3665,
  "time": "2020-08-14T15:06:31.277Z"
}
```

As far as I'm aware there is no performance benefit. It is only advertised as reducing code complexity by eliminating the need for the io code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dynamic filters on the input bindings. The input binding is used in the context of you want to trigger your function by the Cosmos DB (e.g. when a given document is updated or deleted or created). It is not meant to do filtering. What you can do is apply your filtering logic on your function, to decide which documents you want to process and the ones to skip. In terms of filtering directly against Cosmos DB, you can still use the SDK or the API.

Comment: I do not think this is accurate. What you are referring to is the Input triggers. As @Aldracor  mentioned above, Cosmos DB Input bindings can be dynamic if you have the values for all the different parameters in the SQL query. If you do not, then you need to resort to client libraries.

Comment: No I was talking about the function trigger. I meant the input binding for the Cosmos DB. But my answer is definitely wrong because you can actually inject dynamically values coming from the request body or the query string when you configure your input binding. Thank you for calling it out. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp